# Delayed_Job Task Fails because of simple Struct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm having troubles using delayed_job in my rails application. My job fails if I am trying to pass a simple (integer) id via a Struct. This is how the job does look like as of now:

```
  class EventJob < Struct.new(:event_id)
    def perform
      # TODO
    end
  end
```

The body of perform is empty as of now. I'm getting the following failed-error when executing a job like this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(EventJob.new(1))
```

Here's the errorr message:

```
Job failed to load: undefined method `members' for #. Handler: "--- !ruby/struct:EventJob \nevent_id: 1\n"
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:86:in `rescue in payload_object'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:84:in `payload_object'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:94:in `block in invoke_job'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:182:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:182:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:238:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:238:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:166:in `block in work_off'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `times'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `work_off'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:133:in `block (4 levels) in start'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:132:in `block (3 levels) in start'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in start'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:128:in `loop'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:128:in `block in start'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in '
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:127:in `start'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in '
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `'
```

If I remove the Struct.new(:event_id) it is executing the peform method. The strange thing is that I do not have a method called "members". But Struct has a method called members. Is there some kind of compatibility problem between delayed_job and Struct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something weird going with your YAML engine, I believe. Check what YAML::Parser constant is. It should be Psych::Parser.
You should be able to perform:

```
YAML.load "--- !ruby/struct:EventJob \nevent_id: 1\n"
```

in your irb console.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I looked into the parser constant this way: YAML::ENGINE.yamler and it returned "syck". When I execute YAML.load I get this: #<struct EventJob event_id=nil>

Comment: If I set the yamler to "Psych" like that in an initializer file:
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
I am still getting the same error

Comment: In the end of the day, the YAML.load line above should produce EventJob instance with event_id == 1. Unfortunately I have no clue why your YAML is misbehaving..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no idea what might cause this problem. I just returned to a older backup version of my project and now it seems to work again. Sorry I can't give any more detailed information about it other then it broke somewhere down the line.